# Sort a QJsonArray

Tags: c++, json, qt

Suppose I have a function of type:

```
bool sortJson(QJsonArray &);
```

which should sort the `QJsonArray` (and return true) if all members are `double`. I know I can build an auxiliary `QVector`, iterate through the `QJsonArray` and test each element for `isDouble()`, and append to the `QVector`, finally sorting the `QVector`, iterating through it again, and inserting back into the `QJsonArray`.

Is there a nicer way to convert between `QJsonArray` and `QVector<dobule>`? Or, are there short functions with these types?

```
bool jsonToVector(const QJsonArray&, QVector<double>&);
bool vectorToJson(const QVector<double>&, QJsonArray&);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is such a function, but what do you define as an item being a double?

If you have { 0.0, 1, 2.2 }, is that: -

- a list of {float, int, double}
- a list of { double, int, double }
- 3 doubles
- 3 floats

I would say all may be true, as JSON is just a textual representation. If you just want to check if it can be converted to a double, then you can convert a JsonArray to a QVariantList and check if each item can then be converted to a double

```
QVariantList varList = jsonArray.toVariantList();
foreach(QVariant item, varList)
{
    bool bOk;
    item.toDouble(&bOk);
    if(bOk)
    {
        // item can be converted to a double
    }
}
```

Whichever method you choose, I don't believe there's a quick function to sort the json array directly.